# How to update a mapped SVN tag in SubGit?

Tags: subgit

SubGit has mapped a tag in my SVN repository to a Git tag. How can I add commit's to this tag int Git so that SubGit automatically pushes them to the tag in the subversion repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, you have "tags/tagName" in SVN repository, and it corresponds to refs/tags/tagName in Git repository.

If you want to change SVN/Git tag only without touching other branches, do the following from Git working copy:

```
$ git co tagName
```

Now "git status" will show that you're not on any branch.

```
$ git st
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Perform your changes, add, and commit them:

```
$ git add changedFile
$ git commit -m "Change changedFile in tagName."
```

Move 'tagName' tag to the current HEAD. `--force` option will allow you to move the tag even though the 'tagName' tag already exists:

```
$ git tag tagName -f
```

(alternatively you can delete the tag with `tag -d tagName` and recreate it to point to HEAD using `git tag tagName`). Now push the tag to the repository:

```
$ git push origin refs/tags/tagName
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, it worked, although I had to first delete the remote git tag because I got "! [rejected] tagName -> tagName (already exists)" when pushing.